# Excel get percentage of difference between numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to add an equation in a cell which will give me the percentage of a number the difference between two numbers is. For example:

```
Cell A1: 154
Cell B1: 150
```

If I use this equation: 150 - 154, the answer is -4. What I need is an equation to give me what percentage of Cell A1 is Cell B1 - Cell A1. If that makes sense.

I've tried `B1-A1/A1*100` and it gives me 50, but it's clearly not 50%.

I know it seems simple, but I can't seem to make it work for some reason.

Thanks.

Comment: (B1-A1)/A1*100... Try this one

Comment: If you are sure that B1<A1 and A1 <> 0, 1 - (B1/A1) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a percentage difference between two values, the rule (at least the one I learned) is quite simple:

```
=(New value-Old value)/Old Value
```

So in your case it's as simple as:

```
=(A1-B1)/B1
```

Select the cell and format it as percentage

---

Obviously swap these cell references around if `B1` holds the new value.